# SSO in Spring Boot with Active Directory (Multi-tenant)

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, single-sign-on

We have a Multi-Tenant Spring Boot application, and now we want to support SSO with Active Directory for one of the tenants. Am not able to find a suitable solution for this. Would be really helpful if I can get suggestions on how or any reference solution for this requirement.

Comment: How do you distinguish the tenants - via the fully qualified domain name?

Which technology are you using to achieve SSO - SAML / OIDC / SPNEGO (Kerberos)?

Comment: Clarifications:
1. tenants are qualified by the domain name
2. we have not finalized on the technology, but we may want to go with  SAML.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Spring SAML security does not support configuration by 'domain name' / HTTP host header --- you have to build this yourself. At least I have done this myself.